# Migrating Bitbucket Pipelines to Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, bitbucket-pipelines

I've spent some time searching but have yet to come across any information tying Bitbucket to Azure that isn't related to the repositories. Currently, my company uses Bitbucket for all the CI/CD pipelines but will be moving to Azure DevOps soon. Has anyone experienced this or know of good ways to carry over the existing yml code without needing to manually/script change every file to fit Azure?

Looking over the code for both they are quite similar but don't seem to be 1:1. The repository will be staying on Bitbucket for the time being and just the DevOps side of things will be shifting platforms.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I thought the YML code was "universal", meaning in your case that it could be used without any changes, both in Azure Devops pipelines and bitbucket pipelines

Comment: After a lot of looking into it, I don't believe there is a way to easily migrate pipeline code. They are very similar and do a lot of the same stuff, but they use slightly different keywords and structures preventing them from being reused. That said, they do translate easily enough but it would be a manual process.